# Cropping VRT with Shapefile to create new VRT with no dependecy from input

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, vrt, gdalbuildvrt, gdaladdo

I'm new to work with gdal and I'm trying to crop a VRT-File with a shapefile to create a new VRT-File that is independent from the input.
I use ***gdalbuildvrt*** [...] to create the base VRT-File from multiple .tif-Files. Then I use ***gdalwarp*** [...] to crop the VRT-File with a shapefile. This works well until I create overviews in an OVR-File with ***gdaladdo*** [...]. Now I can't delete the first VRT-File without damaging the other one, because the cropped one depends on the first and also to the OVR-File of the first VRT-File.
How can I achieve an independent cropped VRT-File without saving it to multiple cropped .tif-Files and re-VRT-ing it?

Comment: That's not how vrt files work